# Why are some of my in-text references different styles from each other?

Tags: citing, natbib

Why do some of my in-text references have an extra set of brackets around the year, rather than et., al?

### document.bib

```
@article{zi2011quantitative,
    title={Quantitative analysis of transient and sustained transforming growth factor-$\beta$ signaling dynamics},
    author={Zi, Zhike and Feng, Zipei and Chapnick, Douglas A and Dahl, Markus and Deng, Difan and Klipp, Edda and Moustakas, Aristidis and Liu, Xuedong},
    journal={Molecular systems biology},
    volume={7},
    number={1},
    pages={492},
    year={2011},
    publisher={EMBO Press}
}

@article{MatsuokaModeling,
    author = {Matsuoka, Y. and Funahashi, A. and Ghosh, S. and Kitano, H.},
    title = {Modeling and simulation using CellDesigner},
    journal = {Methods Mol Biol},
    volume = {1164},
    pages = {121-45},
    ISSN = {1064-3745},
    DOI = {10.1007/978-1-4939-0805-9_11},
    year = {2014},
    type = {Journal Article}
}
```

### Screen pics of reference in main file

first citation example:

[image]

second citation example:

[image]

----------------edit------------------------

I am using the bioinformatic [template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-oxford-bioinformatics-journal-new-version/zjrmbrmtrytg#.Wjv3mN9l-70)

```
\documentclass{bioinfo}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{humannat}

\begin{document}
This is the first reference (\cite{zi2011quantitative})

This is the second reference (\cite{MatsuokaModeling})


\medskip
\bibliography{example}
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image]

It is strange that this time both references have extra brackets around the year. Is it possible to remove them?

Comment: Are you using bibtex or biblatex? What citation and reference style bcommands? Without knowing this your question is unlikely to be answerable. You should really give us a minimal document that we can compile without effort and reproduces the problem.

Comment: I have modified the question to include an abstracted example. However, now both citations have extra brackets. I'm not actually sure whether I'm using bibtex or biblatex but I'm using tex studio under a windows operating system with Miktex I believe

Comment: @CiaranWelsh: Well, think about it this way... we need to replicate your issue in order to address it. So you'll have to fiddle with it until it reaches that point.

Comment: You wrote, "I'm not actually sure whether I'm using bibtex or biblatex". Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package and employ `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` directives, you can only be using BibTeX, not biblatex, to create the formatted and sorted bibliography.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the `natbib` citation management package, you should familiarize yourself with the `\cite`-type macros provided by `natbib`:

- Under `natbib`, `\cite` is an alias for `\citet` -- think: "textual" citation callout. This command is programmed to create a citation call-out of the form `Zi et al. (2011)`.
- For "parenthetic" citation call-outs, use the command `\citep`; it'll create citation call-outs of the form `(Zi et al., 2011)`.

Do check out the user guide of the `natbib` package for additional citation commands and for ways to customize the appearance of textual and parenthetic citation call-outs.

Comment: Darn it! Can't you just leave the easy ones to freshlings like je? :D

Comment: @thymaro - If you want to take over answering natbib/citing/bibliography/bibtex questions, be my guest! :-)

Comment: If I am to take over answering all of them, in the matter of a year, everybody will suddenly feel the urge to move to biblatex and biber. Not all of them, of course, just the easy ones B)